# Is it possible to wait for text to change to a specific value in Selenium (Python) with a WebElement?

Tags: python, selenium, wait

I have clicked on a button that will update a span.  So now I want to wait for that span to change from a 1 to a 2.  It sounds like I'm trying to do exactly what text_to_be_present_in_element does, except without a locator.  I already have the WebElement I need.  Is it possible to use these expected_conditions functions with an actual WebElement?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could just get the value of the span and have python check once a second (or whatever) to see if it is different than before.